# Why doesn't AWT/Swing repaint automatically when adding a component to a container?

Tags: java, swing, awt

We have some code implemented as follows:

```
@Override
public void showPanel(CardPanel panel)
{
    cardPanel.removeAll();
    cardPanel.add((Component) panel);

    // Even though you'd think adding a component should automatically repaint,
    // it turns out that it doesn't.
    cardPanel.repaint();
}
```

`cardPanel` is just a `JPanel` and `CardPanel` is just one of our own interfaces, but all card panels are just using normal Swing components.

This comment was baffling because, as far as I knew, `Container#add` was supposed to automatically repaint itself if a child was added. Yet, if I delete the line, indeed I do see that it doesn't repaint its contents when the child is added.

Is there some particular reason why `Container` behaves this way? To me, it seems to violate the "principle of least surprise"...

Comment: Admittedly we are displaying this whole thing inside a JIDE dockable panel, and I've seen that library doing Swing stuff incorrectly on multiple occasions in the past, so it could be that they're somehow responsible for this one too...

Comment: How many things are you going to add? This is why you have to add everything before you make it visible, if you make it visible and then add components to the frame you are responsible for triggering the `repaint()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some particular reason why Container behaves this way?

By default all Swing components have a default size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Components are given a size (and location) when the layout manager is invoked. Since you could be adding multiple components to the panel it doesn't make sense for the layout manager to continually be invoked as each component is added.

So when you finish adding components to the panel you do:

```
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // not always needed, but will ensure the panel is repainted.
```

Comment: I thought that, just like how invalidate() is called automatically to mark the layout dirty, revalidate() would be called automatically from somewhere to check whether layout was needed... but obviously I was wrong all along and it was never doing this. (Now I'm wondering whether this is something we can write automated checks for.)